# Common layouts, different resources

Tags: android, android-resources

I need your suggestion for my application. I have written an application two month ago, and now have been asked to write similar application. I've got an idea to change only resources. I'd like to change my application to use different resources but common layouts.

Have you any ideas how to use different resources without replaceing them and renaming as thay are used in application.

Answer (score 2):

Check your old project as a Android library (in project properties in eclipse), create new project, copy manifest to the new project, add old project as a Android library, put new/modified resources to the new. Resources will be overriden.

Comment: Covert the project to MAVEN and use the copy-resource plugin to do what you are doing.